# How to make text appear when you choose a certain option

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sort of stuck with something at the moment. I want to make a DIV with text appear when a user selects one certain option from a select dropdown form. How can this be done in Javascript? What I found online only takes what you selected and shows the value you chose.

Whereas, I want to do something like this:

```
<select>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
</select>

<div id="text" style="display:hidden;">The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"</div>
```

Anyone know how to do this?

UPDATE:

Here's my problem. I've now tried using this Script both in the body and in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('script-choose').onchange=function(){
for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('option-show').length;i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('option-show')[i].style.display='none';
}
document.getElementById(document.getElementById('script-choose').value == 'gold').style.display='block';}
</script>
```

My select form's id is 'script-choose' and the value I'm using to make the hidden text display is 'gold'. No matter when I choose the 'gold' value though, it won't display the text. Here's the DIV I'm using:

```
<div id="one-show" class="option-show" style="font-size:10.5px;color:red;">You will get one free theme of choice later on! :D </div>
```

Comment: Hi, I have a correction in your code.Change display:hidden to display:none. There is no display:hidden. its only visibility: hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, you would like the div to be displayed when 'Two' is selected. For clarity, here is the entire code from start to finish:

```
<select id="mySelect" onchange='on_change(this)'> // Note the onchange event handler, which passes the select object to the on_change function via the 'this' variable
    <option value='one'>One</option> // Note I added value='one'
    <option value='two'>Two</option> // Note I added value='two'
</select>

<div id="text" style="display:none;"> // Note display:none instead of display:hidden
    The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"
</div>

<script>
    function on_change(el){
        if(el.options[el.selectedIndex].value == 'two'){ 
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'; // Show el
        }else{
            document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'; // Hide el
        }
    }
</script>
```

To answer your question, you do not need to replace `el` with the select object, that is passed by using `this` while calling `on_change()` in the select box onChange event handler.

Furthermore, do not take the advice of basically every other answer here.. Importing jQuery to do something as simple as set an event handler and manipulate the DOM is excessive and pointless - Learn JavaScript before you learn jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm still seeing a bit trouble, but I'm not sure. In the script, do I have to replace the 'el' with the name of the select form? When I choose the value Two (because that will display the text) it doesn't display.

Comment: @JakeBrunton Updated answer above..my bad I meant to leave this comment earlier

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should add `value` attributes to the `option`s and have an id on the select, like this:

```
<select id="select-show">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

you should also put an id and class on the div you want to show, like this:

```
<div id="one-show" class="option-show">blah blah blah</div>
```

you will need this css as well:

```
.option-show{
    display:none;
}
```

then also have this script:

```
document.getElementById('select-show').onchange=function(){
    for(var i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName('option-show').length;i++){
        document.getElementsByClassName('option-show')[i].style.display='none';
    }
    document.getElementById(document.getElementById('select-show').value+'-show').style.display='block';
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/kyyxZ/1/

Note that this also makes other divs go away. If you select two, the div 2 will appear. Select one, and 1 will appear and 2 will go away.

Comment: +1 because you didn't add jQuery as a dependency, and the use of CSS classes vs inline styles is definitely preferred

Answer (score 0):

If you can include jQuery in your page, have a look at the working sample here: [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/UtoWaG/2/edit?html,js,output)

Code for reference:

HTML:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
</select>

<div id="text" style="display:none;">The text would show if the user chooses option "Two"</div>
```

Include this jQuery:

```
    $( "#mySelect" ).change(function () {

     if($( "#mySelect").val()=="Two")
          {   
            $( "#text" ).css('display','block');
          }
     else{
       $( "#text" ).css('display','none');
     }
  })
  .change();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use jQuery. It's better to add a class called hidden. which is {display:none}, and you can toggle the visibility of the div easily.

```
 $('select').change(function() {
        var str = $( "select option:selected" ).text();
        if(str  === 'One') {
           $('#text').removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
```